# Inherited Composite Class

Tags: design-patterns, class-design, composite, object-oriented-analysis, anti-patterns

I am working on a pattern and would like to know if this is a good practice to follow - I have class A as super class and classes B and C are child classes (inherited from class A). I want to build a relationship as "B is a Composite class that can have type of A as a property" (i.e B can have a nested type of A) . Is this a valid relationship I can build ? Is there any issues you see in this relationship

Comment: Yes indeed it is valid. Child extends Parent and Child class having a instance of Parent is a valid design. For reference have a look to Decorator pattern, Composite Pattern

Comment: If B has a single reference to A, the the resulting object structure is an object list like what you see with the Decorator pattern. If B has a reference to a composition of As (like an array), you get the tree structure typical of the Composite pattern.